# Listening for double power button presses when the screen is off

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to execute a set of codes when the power button is pressed twice when the screen is off. The code given below is working perfectly but i dont know if it is efficient or is there any better way to do this. Any changes is appreciated.

I have implemented this in a foreground service.

**MyService.java**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "in onstartcommand()");
    IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter();
    inf.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    inf.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            temp_intent = intent;
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                         
                            if(temp_intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                            main_flag+=1;
                            if(main_flag == 2){
                                Log.i(TAG, "Double Press Detected ");
                                //Do Something here
                                main_flag=1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(rec, inf);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Creating a service:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class UnlockService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        UnlockService getService() {
            return UnlockService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a Receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.e("LOB","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;

        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Log.e("LOB","userpresent");
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
            String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
            context.startActivity(i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Add in Manifest

```
  <service android:name=".UnlockService" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```